# Create a LongTextArea custom Field and show this in Layout

Tags: apex, metadata-api, custom-field, long-text-area

I have a problem creating a LongTextArea custom field. I don't understand what is wrong, if it's actually not created or not visible as a field.

This is my code:

```
    CustomField customField = new CustomField();
    customField.setFullName(fullName);
    customField.setDescription(description);
    customField.setType(fieldType);
    customField.setLabel(label);
    customField.setRequired(true);

    if (fieldType.equals(FieldType.LongTextArea)) {
        customField.setLength(32000);
        customField.setVisibleLines(30);
    }
```

This is wrong? Any help will be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Replace `Test__c` with your custom object api name.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Test__c.LongTextAreaField__c';
customField.label = 'Long Text Area Field';
customField.type_x = 'LongTextArea';
customField.length = 32000;
customField.visibleLines = 3;
MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results = service.create(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { customField });
```

Comment: Using metadata api it's what i am doing. it does not throw any errors on create :(

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: I had to delete some lines: customField.setTrackFeedHistory(true);
    customField.setTrackHistory(true);
    customField.setRequired(true); and then it worked